# How to search the match value with php from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a problem here about how to search an exact value from database. Here i have my codes that are function normally but the problem is, when i search the value for example i search for "T1" and then the result show me for "T1", "T11", "T12", "T13" and some more. I just only the value that match with "T1" only be shown. Here my codes below

```
<?php
include_once("mysql_connect.php");
$output1 = '';
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['select']))  {
$selectq = $_POST['select'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asset_a WHERE Tag_no LIKE '%$selectq%' or         

Speciality LIKE '%$selectq%' ") or die("could not search!");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = 'There was no search results!';
}else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $tag = $row['Tag_no'];
        $special = $row['Speciality'];
        $output1 .= $special;
      }
   }

}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="testq.php" >
 <label for="textfield" style="font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro',
 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px">
 Tag No:</label>
 <select name="select" id="select" class="textfields" >
    <option value="0">-- Select your tag no --</option>
    <?php
    $getallAsset_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asset_a ");
    while($viewallAsset_a = mysql_fetch_array($getallAsset_a)){
        ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $viewallAsset_a ['Tag_id'];?>"><?php echo
        $viewallAsset_a['Tag_no']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>   

  <input type="image" name="submit" id="submit" src="../Search.png" 

  formaction="testq.php" >

</p>
</select>

<p>
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input type="text" name="special" id="textfield"value="<?php print ("$output1");?>" >
</p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you use 'LIKE' in the first place if you want to find exact value ?

Comment: Sidenote: Remove `formaction="testq.php"` from your input.

Comment: Try '%$selectq%' without %'s like this '$selectq' .

Comment: thanks guys! Its work. I just need to remove the sign "%". Thanks alot. =)